# Big-O of while loop nested inside for loop is O(n), why?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to figure out why the following is O(n). My doubt is actually on how to figure out the number of iterations of the inner loop *without substituting the values*.

*Edit: In other words, can anyone show me the derivation using sigma notation?

```
n = 10
j = 1
for i in range(n):
      while j < i:
        j *= 2
```

It is easy to see that the inner `while` will be executed at most one time per `i` value, but I am struggling to see more generally how to figure out the last value for `j` in order to perform the corresponding manipulations in the sums using T(n). Can anyone show the calculation?

Comment: The inner loop will never do more than one iteration. That `while` could have been an `if` with the same result.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you struggling to prove that the while-loop has at most 1 iteration?

Comment: Hi @Stef, I am struggling to prove it with sigma notation actually. Will edit the question in order to clarify.

Comment: Step 1: If `C(i)` is the complexity of the while-loop at iteration `i`, prove that the total complexity `T(n)`of the code is `Sum_i C(i)`. Step 2: Prove that the while-loop has complexity `O(1)`; in other words, `forall i, C(i) = O(1)`. Step 3: Combine steps 1 and 2 to get `T(n) = O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 10
j = 1
for i in range(n):
      while j < i:
        j *= 2
```

Iteration 1: `i = 1` and `1 < 1` is false;

Iteration 2: `i = 2` and `1 < 2` is true, => `j` becomes 1 * 2 = 2; (`i = 2` and `j = 2`);

Iteration 3: `i = 3` and `2 < 3` is true, => `j` becomes 2 * 2 = 4; (`i = 3` and `j = 4`);

Iteration 4: `i = 4` and `4 < 4` is false; (`i = 4` and `j = 4`);

Iteration 5: `i = 5` and `4 < 5` is true, => `j` becomes 2 * 4 = 8; (`i = 5` and `j = 8`);

. . .

then `j = 8` will NOT be less than i for the next three iterations..

then `j` will be less than 9 and so on.

So, there are iterations where `j < i` evaluates to true, but even in those cases, that nested `while` loop doesn't live long.

It is a bit *amortized*, but overall, `while j < i` is still a very much lower order term.

Therefore, according to the asymptotic measurement, higher order is *O*(n).

Comment: In fact I think you could replace the `while` with an `if` in this case.  Can you think of a circumstance where you'd need `j*=2` more than once?

Comment: Hi @Giorgi, thanks a lot. As stated this much I could verify, what I am struggling with is seen this in a more abstract (mathematical) fashion, without needing to do it explicitly as you did.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a more abstract way of analyzing it which complements the previous answer and comments.

Notice that:

1. The variable `j` of the `while loop` is defined *outside* of the `for loop`, which implies that if `j < i` is satisfied, `j` will be updated and after that, a new iteration of the `for loop` happens, updating `i`.
2. Since `j` is not reset to 1 at each iteration of the `for loop`, we expect that
   the number of runs of the be O(n) < Log_2(n), which suggests that it is O(1).
3. By inspection (as in the previous answer) we can confirm (2.), where for each `i` the while loop will run at most one time.

Comment:
I am a newbie on this and I was looking for a more closed mathematical proof using sigma notation in a similar fashion as in other cases with nested loops, where the total number of runs of the inner loops can be found as sums of elements of arithmetic or geometric progressions for instance, depending of the case. But the using arguments (1.) and (2.) was the closer I could get.

Anyways, many thanks for the help  :)